# Python Issue writing txt file

Tags: python, file, beautifulsoup, txt

I'm trying to write element I parsered with beautifulsoup in python to a txt file, I need to truncate it before writing because it will be updated.

this is how I write element I parsered

```
url = "https://rocket-league.com/trade/465ec00f-2f5c-48e2-831e-2e294683ad56"
response = requests.get(f"{url}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

for e in soup.select('.rlg-trade__itemshas .--hover'):
    items = (' '.join(list(e.stripped_strings)[:-2]))
    lstitem = (f"[H] " f"{items}" + f"\n")
    with open("hs.txt", "a") as h:
        h.write(lstitem)
```

output:

```
[H] Magma
[H] Pink Light Show
[H] Cristiano
[H] Anodized Pearl
```

but when I write it again, output:

```
[H] Magma
[H] Pink Light Show
[H] Cristiano
[H] Anodized Pearl
[H] Magma
[H] Pink Light Show
[H] Cristiano
[H] Anodized Pearl
```

i use `h.truncate(0)` for truncate before writing, but output like this:

```
[H] Anodized Pearl
```

what should I do to interrupt output during loop as if it were first output

Comment: If you open the file in `'w'` mode instead of `'a'` mode it will give the correct output each time, unless there are other reasons not to do that

Comment: Why are you continually opening and closing the file in the loop? Perhaps open it once before you enter the loop with mode 'w'

Comment: @mousetail If the code shown in the question is edited to use mode 'w' the output file will only ever have (at most) one line in it

Comment: i tried it with `w` mode, but it still output like last output

Comment: i do not close or open file while I am in loop, I want to update the file because elements I have parsered have changed, but I want it to be latest updated output

Comment: @yusufkuşçu I strongly recommend that you look at the answer I've provided and try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be opening the file for writing before entering the selection loop. Like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

OUTPUT = 'hs.txt'
url = "https://rocket-league.com/trade/465ec00f-2f5c-48e2-831e-2e294683ad56"
(response := requests.get(url)).raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
with open(OUTPUT, 'w') as h:
    for e in soup.select('.rlg-trade__itemshas .--hover'):
        item = ' '.join(list(e.stripped_strings)[:-2])
        print(f'[H] {item}', file=h)
```